# How to set onkeypress or onkeydown only one time click?

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I am trying to use onkeypress or onkeydown one time click after it's clicked than the onkeypress will remove but I am unable to do that, and tried but not working which I have tried.

here is my snippet below.

```js
textarea.onkeypress = myPress;

    function myPress(){
        let setTime = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);
        function timeUpdate(){
            time.innerHTML =Number(time.innerHTML)+1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="time">0</div>
    <textarea  name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

According to my snippet, when I am typing the onkeypress looks like multiple clicked and setInterval behave like not going the time every 1 seconds, 
so I need to put every one second when I am typing inside textarea.
Thanks.

Comment: `setInterval` will fire every seconds, did you mean to use `setTimeout` instead..

Comment: no, try my snippet. when I am typing each time the seconds is increasing the speed and it's not going every 1 seconds, test it

Comment: try to typing fast some word and you will understand what I wanted the seconds will also increase the speed that I don't wanted

Comment: I did test it, but to be honest I'm not sure what your trying to do.  Every time you do a keypress you going to be creating another `setInterval`, so yes it will go faster as after pressing 10 times, you will have 10 `setIntervals` that are going to fire every 1/10th of a second..  What is it your trying to achieve?..

Comment: so you want to have time running above your text area once the user has started typing is that correct?

Comment: for example, I am trying if I click any key than the setInterval start but not wanted onkeypress multiple times just if I click any key than setInterval start

Comment: you can clear old interval and create new one

Comment: In that case, any of the below answers should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a trace of the previous triggered event. An alternative could be a variable outside of the handler or a [`data attribute (aka dataset in js)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) in the element which is a kind of flag.

```js
document.querySelector("#textarea").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  if (time.dataset.time === "-1") {
    time.dataset.time = "1";
    setInterval(function() {
      time.innerHTML = Number(time.textContent) + 1; //Using textContent we access the text without any applied style to the element.
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="time" data-time="-1">0</div>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

If the handler won't be used in the future, you can [remove the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

```js
let handler = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      time.innerHTML = Number(time.textContent) + 1; //Using textContent we access the text without any applied style to the element.
    }, 1000);
    
    this.removeEventListener("keypress", handler);
};

let textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea");
textarea.addEventListener("keypress", handler);
```

```html
<div id="time" data-time="-1">0</div>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the event once the Interval is set.

```js
textarea.onkeypress = myPress;

    function myPress(){
        let setTime = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);
        textarea.onkeypress = null;
        function timeUpdate(){
            time.innerHTML =Number(time.innerHTML)+1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="time">0</div>
    <textarea  name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add and remove event listeners. At the moment it's firing on every keypress, not just the first one. Something like:

```
function myPress() {
    textarea.removeEventListener('keypress', myPress, false);
    // Do something else here
}

const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keypress', myPress, false);
```

There's a full rundown of addEventListener on MDN which should help explain in more detail how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener